# Approximating missing data points in a list using fit models

Tags: fitting, approximation

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l={0, 76, 413, 942, 1344, 1651, 1486, 1013, 581, 237, 65, 17, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I want to find a fit to this curve so I do the following:

```
n = 26;
model = Sum[Subscript[j, i]*x^i, {i, n}];
x1 = FindFit[LL2, model, Table[Subscript[j, i], {i, n}], x];
x2 = Table[model /. x1, {x, n}];
p1 = ListPlot[x2, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p1, LL2 // ListPlot, PlotRange -> All]
```

for which I get:

[image]

where the red line is fitting the blue data points. Yet I am a little suspicious of my method. Namely if such polynomial, I made in `model`, if the real fit to my data? Is this the best way to find curve fit?

Now suppose I have another list with missing points such as:

```
    data = {30082, 565639, 4084651, 16288517, 44188452, 93408435, Missing[], Missing[], Missing[],
Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], 51768887, 19465081, 6254533, 
      1693334, 378976, 68265, 9514, 963, 63, 2}
```

I wonder how can I approximate the missing point?

Comment: But why? You can just give 2D coordinates to `FindFit`, or `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @corey979 the problems are the missing points in `data` - see end of my question, I can make 2D coordinates by: Transpose[{Range[30], data}] and run the `FindFit` or `NonLinearModelFit` but when plotting the result it is not a proper fit as I have zeros in data...

Comment: Do you know already that the model should be a 26-term polynomial? It looks like you only have 26 data points. A 26-term polynomial will get a perfect fit with zero error... but does the model mean anything? If you try to extrapolate past the ends of your data even slightly, you'll probably find that your model veers off sharply or does some other weird thing. Usually your model will have (a lot) fewer fitting parameters than data points, but your application might be different than what I'm used to.

Comment: @MassDefect indeed I do count what you've mentioned into account and hence wrote I am suspicious of the polynomial model... My main problem is how to tackle a curve when you have missing data points. What's the conventional technique to approximate them in Mathematica

Comment: It is unclear what is missing. `data` has 30 elements, none of which is `Missing[]`. Do you treat the zeros as missing? Then just drop them from the data set.

Comment: Your data set consists of integers.  If these are frequency counts from some probability distribution, then you should not be performing a regression.  And if a regression is appropriate, you need to account for non-constant variance.  So describing how the data was obtained and why some data values are missing seems essential.

Comment: @corey979 indeed I've treated 0s as missing - Please see the update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): the OP asks how to interpolate data before fitting, but interpolation is not needed for the fitting at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way that I would treat this sort of data would be to assign explicit x-values and then fit to a known model while excluding the `Missing[]` points. Your data looks pretty Gaussian to me, though it's usually best if you can justify the model first and then apply it. Here, I'm taking a guess at a model and then justifying it because it looks good, but that's really the opposite of how it should be done.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}] /. {_, Missing[]} -> Nothing, 
  a PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x], 
  {{a, 10^8}, {\[Mu], 12}, {\[Sigma], 5}}, 
  x
]
Show[
  ListPlot[
    data,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], ColorData[75][5]]
  ],
  Plot[
    nlm[x],
    {x, 0, 30},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], ColorData[85][1]]
  ]
]
```

[image: Poster's data with Gaussian fit.]

Depending on what your data is representing, this may not be the correct model, but perhaps it will give you some ideas about how to proceed.